# Shortened version of a math book (without proofs)

Tags: mathematics, writing, copyright, books, monograph

I've authored a math research monograph (which can be however used as a textbook, as it is structured like a textbook).

Is it worth to make short version of it containing only definitions and theorems (no proofs) in the natural pedagogical order (not the order of proofs, as in the actual book)?

Will it be legal after copyright transfer?

Comment: What is the purpose of such a book ? Mathematics without proof sounds strange. Or do you mean to make a handbook ?

Comment: There is "main" book with proofs. I consider to create **also** a short version without proofs, only with results.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to talk with your publisher (and lawyer) about what rights you retain after transfer.